# Unable to open remotely installed sonar on a browser

Tags: linux, sonarqube

I have installed sonar on a remote Linux cent OS server. I have configured the database on the same server. When I start the server, I don't see any errors in the logs and the sonar seems running. 
message:
[sonar]$ ./bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh status
sonar is running (13429).

But, when I try to access sonar from my windows pc through a browser, it gives me a connection timed out error. 
I tried access via chrome and firefox browser with the following URL.
http://:9000/sonar
Is this the right way to do it?
Is there anything else I am missing here? I haven't set up anything else like maven/jenkins/tomcat integration or anything as such. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Following are the values I had given:
sonar.web.host:                           127.0.0.1
sonar.web.port:                           9000
sonar.web.context:                        /sonar
```

Logs:

```
    STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/10/01 11:08:57 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/10/01 11:08:58 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/01 11:08:58 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/01 11:08:58 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/01 11:08:58 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/01 11:08:58 | 2013-10-01 11:08:58.578:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.11.v20130520
2013.10.01 11:09:01 INFO  o.s.s.p.ServerImpl  SonarQube Server / 3.7.1 / 7f8f4d0f0b0044f178d587b8680032734d4fb578
2013.10.01 11:09:01 INFO  o.s.c.p.Database  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonarqube?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatem
ents=true
2013.10.01 11:09:02 INFO  o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem  SonarQube home: /apps/sonar
2013.10.01 11:09:02 INFO  o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem  Deploy dir: /apps/sonar/war/sonar-server/deploy
2013.10.01 11:09:02 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Install plugins...
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 1.3 / 4d7d78e9340e39f53bbf202ed16d1253e6507c36
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin JaCoCo / 1.3 / 4d7d78e9340e39f53bbf202ed16d1253e6507c36
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin English Pack / 3.7.1 / 7f8f4d0f0b0044f178d587b8680032734d4fb578
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Maven Batch Plugin / 3.7.1 / 7f8f4d0f0b0044f178d587b8680032734d4fb578
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Surefire / 1.3 / 4d7d78e9340e39f53bbf202ed16d1253e6507c36
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Duplications / 3.7.1 / 7f8f4d0f0b0044f178d587b8680032734d4fb578
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Checkstyle / 1.3 / 4d7d78e9340e39f53bbf202ed16d1253e6507c36
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin PMD / 1.3 / 4d7d78e9340e39f53bbf202ed16d1253e6507c36
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Java / 1.3 / 4d7d78e9340e39f53bbf202ed16d1253e6507c36
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Core / 3.7.1 / 7f8f4d0f0b0044f178d587b8680032734d4fb578
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Database Cleaner / 3.7.1 / 7f8f4d0f0b0044f178d587b8680032734d4fb578
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Squid for Java / 1.3 / 4d7d78e9340e39f53bbf202ed16d1253e6507c36
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 3.7.1 / 7f8f4d0f0b0044f178d587b8680032734d4fb578
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Design / 3.7.1 / 7f8f4d0f0b0044f178d587b8680032734d4fb578
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Install plugins done: 241 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.s.p.ApplicationDeployer  Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Start components...
2013.10.01 11:09:03 INFO  o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector  Initializing Hibernate
2013.10.01 11:09:05 INFO  o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient  Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2013.10.01 11:09:05 INFO  o.s.s.n.NotificationService  Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2013.10.01 11:09:05 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Deploy GWT plugins...
2013.10.01 11:09:05 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Deploy org.sonar.plugins.design.ui.libraries.LibrariesPage to /apps/sonar/war/sonar-server/deploy/gwt
2013.10.01 11:09:05 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Deploy org.sonar.plugins.design.ui.page.DesignPage to /apps/sonar/war/sonar-server/deploy/gwt
2013.10.01 11:09:05 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Deploy GWT plugins done: 32 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:05 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Load metrics...
2013.10.01 11:09:06 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics  cleaning alert thresholds...
2013.10.01 11:09:06 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Load metrics done: 498 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:06 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [findbugs/java]...
2013.10.01 11:09:07 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [findbugs/java] done: 611 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:07 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [checkstyle/java]...
2013.10.01 11:09:07 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [checkstyle/java] done: 543 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:07 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [pmd/java]...
2013.10.01 11:09:08 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [pmd/java] done: 841 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:08 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [pmd-unit-tests/java]...
2013.10.01 11:09:08 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [pmd-unit-tests/java] done: 38 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:08 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [squid/java]...
2013.10.01 11:09:08 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [squid/java] done: 220 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:08 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [common-java/java]...
2013.10.01 11:09:08 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [common-java/java] done: 6 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:08 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterRules  Removing deprecated rules
2013.10.01 11:09:09 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterNewProfiles  Register Quality Profiles...
2013.10.01 11:09:11 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterNewProfiles  Register Quality Profiles done: 2401 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:11 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterQualityModels  Register Quality Models...
2013.10.01 11:09:11 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterQualityModels  Register Quality Models done: 0 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:12 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters  Register measure filters...
2013.10.01 11:09:12 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters  Register measure filters done: 6 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:12 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterNewDashboards  Register dashboards...
2013.10.01 11:09:12 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterNewDashboards  Register dashboards done: 18 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:12 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates  Register permission templates...
2013.10.01 11:09:12 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates  Register permission templates done: 2 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:12 INFO  o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys  Rename deprecated property keys
2013.10.01 11:09:12 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Start components done: 8602 ms
2013.10.01 11:09:12 INFO  jruby.rack  jruby 1.6.8 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-09-18 1772b40) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_22) [linux-amd64-java]
2013.10.01 11:09:12 INFO  jruby.rack  using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/01 11:09:18 | JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/01 11:09:18 | gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/01 11:09:26 | 2013-10-01 11:09:26.032:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/sonar,file:/apps/sonar/war/sonar-server/},file:/apps/sonar/war/sonar-server
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/01 11:09:26 | 2013-10-01 11:09:26.107:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:9000
```

The permissions of the folders in the Sonar directory:

```
drwxrwxrwx 13 usr grp     4096 Sep 30 15:53 bin
drwxrwxrwx  2 usr grp     4096 Oct  1 12:36 conf
-rwxrwxrwx  1 usr grp     7651 Sep 30 15:53 COPYING
drwxrwxrwx  2 usr grp     4096 Sep 30 15:53 data
drwxrwxrwx  7 usr grp     4096 Sep 30 16:02 extensions
drwxrwxrwx  3 usr grp     4096 Sep 30 15:53 lib
drwxrwxrwx  2 usr grp     4096 Oct  1 10:23 logs
-rwxrwxrwx  1 usr grp 74135040 Sep 30 15:17 sonar.tar
drwxrwxrwx  3 usr grp     4096 Oct  1 12:58 temp
drwxrwxrwx  4 usr grp     4096 Sep 30 15:53 war
```

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your server's sonar.properties file, you'll need to set the host information in order to access the server remotely.

Specifically, you need to set the following values:

```
sonar.web.host: 192.168.1.1 #use your server IP here
sonar.web.port: 80 #set this if you want a different port than 9000
```

Also, in the web UI's Settings area, under the "General" section, set the "Server base URL" value so that links in generate emails, etc, point to the right location. This can also be set in your sonar.properties file as sonar.core.serverBaseURL

Don't forget to restart the Sonar service for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks John. Have made the changes. But, I don't reach the UI screen. Getting another sort of permision issue though there is full permission on files within the sonar directory

Comment: I found that `sonar.host.url=http://localhost:80` works also. The Port can be included in the URL. The most important part is that you place it in the *server's sonar-scanner.properties* file and not the `sonar-scanner.properties` file that exist in the repo you want to scan.

Answer (score 4):

By default sonar listens on localhost so you can access sonar through only localhost you have to make it listen on remote hosts by changing the parameter url in sonar-runner.properties. You have to keep the local ip of the linux server instead of 127.0.0.1

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Seems there was an issue with the port. It was not opened by the server admin. The port is now opened and I have changed the value of sonar.web.host to the IP address of the remote machine. Now I am getting a permissions error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following directory can not be created: /apps/sonar/war/sonar-server/deploy
        at org.sonar.server.platform.DefaultServerFileSystem.start(DefaultServerFileSystem.java:89) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: I have added the permissions of the directories within sonar.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was, I had to allow port in `iptables` and not append(default) it but add it in front of rule "`drop all`", which negated everything after.

command:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```

where 1 - defines at which(1st) position of iptable rules to add it

Answer (score 0):

Change the `sonar.properties` as below and restart the Sonar server. This should make Sonar accessible over the network and not limited to localhost

```
sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0
```