# Unable to access Sonar Dashboard from another/remote Windows/Mac machine

Tags: macos, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I tried setting up SonarQube analysis with jenkins using sonar-runner plugin. I am able to access the dashboard locally and I have no problems with that.To access the sonar dashboard from another machine I changed the ip address mentioned in sonar.web.host and restarted the sonar service. Still i am not able to view the dashboard in my remote machine. My machine is a MAC machine. Can anyone help out?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change `sonar.web.host` from it's default, it's just a binding IP address. What have you tried to debug this ? Can you ping the Mac remotely ? What error do you get ? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: I went through stackoverflow pages and found that sonar.web.host needs to be changed to the ip address on which sonar-runner is used(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114259/unable-to-open-remotely-installed-sonar-on-a-browser) and that is the reason behind changing it. I was able to access jenkins from other machines but not the sonar dashboard link that comes up in the console output. Tried giving <ip-address on which sonar-runner is present>:9000 still no luck and i got connection timed out error.

Comment: No, `sonar.web.host` must correspond to an IP address of your server. Please edit your question with version of SonarQube and values you tried for `sonar.web.host`.

Comment: Try using port 80 to exclude firewall issues