# Unable to access new SonarQube install (v5.6.6) from machines other than the host server

Tags: sonarqube

I'm new to Sonar and this is a new install on a CentOS 7 machine. I have seen other similar questions, but I have not been able to translate the replies into changes that work for me.

I am using MySQL (Community version -- not the MariaDB that CentOS seems to favor now).

I was hopeful that these changes to the "sonar.properties" file would have done the trick.  They did not:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.password=mypassword
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
sonar.web.host=mysonar.mynetwork.mycompany.com
sonar.web.context=/
sonar.web.port=9000
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx768m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start simple by commenting-out _sonar.web.host_ . It's an optional property only in case you which SonarQube to listen on a specific network interface.

Comment: Thanks @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam and Nicolas for your ideas. I did comment out sonar.web.host as Nicolas suggested.  I think the change that did the trick though was the one taken from the third solution--the one with 0 votes--presented in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114259/unable-to-open-remotely-installed-sonar-on-a-browser thread sited by G.Ann